# TypeError: Cannot set property 'styles' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, node-modules

While running "npm run dev" in my next.js project, I'm getting this error
[Image showing the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/529HF.png)

```
info  - Disabled SWC as replacement for Babel because of custom Babel configuration ".babelrc" https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled
TypeError: Cannot set property 'styles' of undefined
    at module.exports (/home/gene/Documents/Internship/grassroots-web/web-app/node_modules/@zeit/next-css/css-loader-config.js:25:56)
    at Object.webpack (/home/gene/Documents/Internship/grassroots-web/web-app/node_modules/@zeit/next-css/index.js:15:36)
    at Object.getBaseWebpackConfig [as default] (/home/gene/Documents/Internship/grassroots-web/web-app/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack-config.js:1388:32)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/home/gene/Documents/Internship/grassroots-web/web-app/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:74:20)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/home/gene/Documents/Internship/grassroots-web/web-app/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:74:20)
    at async HotReloader.start (/home/gene/Documents/Internship/grassroots-web/web-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-reloader.js:329:25)
    at async DevServer.prepare (/home/gene/Documents/Internship/grassroots-web/web-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:296:9)

> Blockquote
```

I'm using TypeScript with next.js in the project and I even checked the presets and plugins all are fine

```
       {
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "styled-components",
      {
        "ssr": true,
        "displayName": true,
        "preprocess": false
      }
    ]
]
}
```

Comment: Remove @zeit/next-css from your project. It has been deprecated for around 2 years. Next.js has built in support for CSS. You don't need that.

Comment: Also you can remove your `.babelrc`. Just set `experimental: { styledComponents: true }` in your `next.config.js`.